# Extracting string pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
chr1    156706559   rs8658  A   C,G 370.29  PASS    AC=1,1;AF=0.500,0.500;AN=2;DB;DP=19;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=1,1;MLEAF=0.500,0.500;MQ=56.74;MQ0=0;POSITIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=19.49;VQSLOD=6.27;culprit=FS;EFF=3_prime_UTR_variant(MODIFIER||123|c.*123A>C|RRNAD1|protein_coding|CODING|NM_001142560.1|7)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/2:0,7,12:19:99:503,293,272,210,0,183
chr10   22839463    rs10047326  C   A,T 202.29  PASS    AC=1,1;AF=0.500,0.500;AN=2;DB;DP=10;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=1,1;MLEAF=0.500,0.500;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;POSITIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=20.23;VQSLOD=10.48;culprit=FS;EFF=intron_variant(MODIFIER|||c.792+125G>T|PIP4K2A|protein_coding|CODING|NM_005028.4|7)    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/2:0,6,4:10:99:317,127,109,190,0,178
chr10   75673731    rs2227566   C   G,T 735.29  PASS    AC=1,1;AF=0.500,0.500;AN=2;DB;DP=33;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=1,1;MLEAF=0.500,0.500;MQ=55.90;MQ0=0;QD=22.28;VQSLOD=6.01;culprit=FS;EFF=splice_region_variant(LOW|||c.630C>G|PLAU|protein_coding|CODING|NM_001145031.1|6)   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/2:0,8,25:33:99:913,734,710,179,0,110
chr12   54805753    rs1922254   G   C,T 404.66  PASS    AC=1,1;AF=0.500,0.500;AN=2;DB;DP=18;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=1,1;MLEAF=0.500,0.500;MQ=55.34;MQ0=0;QD=22.48;VQSLOD=5.61;culprit=FS;EFF=splice_region_variant(LOW|||c.219C>G|ITGA5|protein_coding|CODING|NM_002205.2|1) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/2:0,4,14:18:67:540,434,422,106,0,67
chr15   50150903    rs7497350   C   A,T 3655.29 PASS    AC=1,1;AF=0.500,0.500;AN=2;DB;DP=140;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=1.8136;MLEAC=1,1;MLEAF=0.500,0.500;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;POSITIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=26.11;VQSLOD=10.96;culprit=FS;EFF=3_prime_UTR_variant(MODIFIER||1488|c.*1488G>T|ATP8B4|protein_coding|CODING|NM_024837.3|28)    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/2:0,62,78:140:99:4121,2349,2187,1772,0,1553
chr16   11678403    rs8054918   T   C,G 283.29  PASS    AC=1,1;AF=0.500,0.500;AN=2;DB;DP=18;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=1,1;MLEAF=0.500,0.500;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;QD=15.74;VQSLOD=10.55;culprit=FS;EFF=intron_variant(MODIFIER|||c.-6+1599A>G|LITAF|protein_coding|CODING|NM_004862.3|1)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/2:0,9,9:18:99:407,181,160,226,0,208
chr16   78503259    rs2738676   G   A,C 166.31  PASS    AC=1,1;AF=0.500,0.500;AN=2;DB;DP=9;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=1,1;MLEAF=0.500,0.500;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;QD=18.48;VQSLOD=10.91;culprit=QD;EFF=intron_variant(MODIFIER|||c.717+36610G>A|WWOX|protein_coding|CODING|NM_001291997.1|7)   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/2:0,3,6:9:80:279,181,172,98,0,80
chr17   4205297 rs1866174   C   A,T 189.29  PASS    AC=1,1;AF=0.500,0.500;AN=2;DB;DP=12;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=1,1;MLEAF=0.500,0.500;MQ=47.61;MQ0=0;POSITIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=15.77;VQSLOD=3.80;culprit=MQ;EFF=intron_variant(MODIFIER|||c.149+5019G>T|UBE2G1|protein_coding|CODING|NM_003342.4|2) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/2:0,5,7:12:87:307,202,187,105,0,87
```

Would like to extract "EFF= ....." from each line, in the above example the output desired is

```
EFF=3_prime_UTR_variant
EFF=intron_variant
EFF=splice_region_variant
```

the above output is for first three lines.

What I have tried.

```
grep -no 'EFF="[^"]*"' file.txt
```

It doesn't work.

Kindly help

Comment: I don't get your `name=` in your grep command, in fact I see no relation between your sample input and your grep command.

Comment: Sorry, it has to be EFF

Comment: Actually your regex try to match EFF= followed by a quoted text `"[^"]*"` suppress the quote and use `\w*` to capture chars only (it will stop on the first non char, here `(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -o "EFF=\w*" /root/testSO
```

gives:

```
EFF=3_prime_UTR_variant
EFF=intron_variant
EFF=splice_region_variant
EFF=splice_region_variant
EFF=3_prime_UTR_variant
EFF=intron_variant
EFF=intron_variant
EFF=intron_variant
```

- -o print only the matching part in output

`EFF=\w*` is the regex telling to match literraly `EFF=` followed by any word character  (a toz A to Z 0 to 9 or _) represented by `\w` and `*` means last class (`\w`) repeated 0 or more time

Note after editing:
First answer used the `-n` command line option to add number on output, was by just fixing the OP command and not taking in account the whole question. Thanks @ChrisMae for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to try:

```
grep -Po 'EFF=[^(]*' file.txt
```

Output:

```
EFF=3_prime_UTR_variant
EFF=intron_variant
EFF=splice_region_variant
EFF=splice_region_variant
EFF=3_prime_UTR_variant
EFF=intron_variant
EFF=intron_variant
EFF=intron_variant
```

---

```
grep -Po 'EFF=\K[^(]*' file.txt
```

```
3_prime_UTR_variant
intron_variant
splice_region_variant
splice_region_variant
3_prime_UTR_variant
intron_variant
intron_variant
intron_variant
```

Comment: you can then remove multiple entries with 
`your_command | sort -u`

Answer (score 1):

awk can help you. This command:

```
awk 'match($0, /EFF=([^(]+)/, arr) { print arr[1]}' file.txt
```

will extract the variables you are probably looking for.

```
3_prime_UTR_variant
intron_variant
splice_region_variant
```

If you really want the `EFF=` part; this command should do (thanks @Tensibai)

```
awk 'match($0, /EFF=([^(]+)/, arr) { print "EFF="arr[1]}' file.txt
```

this gives:

```
EFF=3_prime_UTR_variant
...
```

Comment: Why not `print "EFF="arr[1]` to match OP question ? And would you mind giving more details on how work your answer for all to be able to understand it ?

Comment: As a side note, worth noting this format of `match` is a gawk extension and won't work on all awk versions. (sorry for double comment)

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o 'EFF=[^(]*' input
```

should do